# How to convert an array of nested objects to an object with key, value pairs in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of nested objects, and I would like to simplify it a bit and convert it to an object with key, value pairs, so the result would be like this:

Simple Object:

```
{Groceries: {
    'Organic eggs': null,
    Fruits: {
        Apple: null,
        Berries: {
            Blueberry: null,
            Raspberry: null
        }
    }
}}
```

Array of nested objects:

```
const tree = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Groceries",
    "parentId": null,
    "children": [{
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Organic eggs",
            "parentId": 1,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Fruits",
            "parentId": 1,
            "children": [{
                    "id": 6,
                    "name": "Apple",
                    "parentId": 5,
                    "children": []
                },{
                    "id": 7,
                    "name": "Berries",
                    "parentId": 5,
                    "children": [{
                            "id": 8,
                            "name": "Blueberry",
                            "parentId": 7,
                            "children": []
                        },{
                            "id": 9,
                            "name": "Raspberry",
                            "parentId": 7,
                            "children": []
                        }]
                }]
        }]
}]
```

Comment: Please add the code you've tried.

Comment: sure, right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using recursion, you can pass your array `tree` and loop through it. If you encounter an object in your tree array which has children, you can pass this child array back to your function to build a new simplified object from this sub-array. If the length of the object's `children` property is `0`, then you can set the simplified object's name property to be `null`.

See example below:

```js
const tree = [{ "id": 1, "name": "Groceries", "parentId": null, "children": [{ "id": 3, "name": "Organic eggs", "parentId": 1, "children": [] }, { "id": 5, "name": "Fruits", "parentId": 1, "children": [{ "id": 6, "name": "Apple", "parentId": 5, "children": [] }, { "id": 7, "name": "Berries", "parentId": 5, "children": [{ "id": 8, "name": "Blueberry", "parentId": 7, "children": [] }, { "id": 9, "name": "Raspberry", "parentId": 7, "children": [] }] }] }] }];

const simplifyObj = arr => {
  const obj = {};
  for(const {name, children} of arr)
    obj[name] = children.length ? simplifyObj(children) : null;
  return obj;
}

const simple = simplifyObj(tree);
console.log(simple);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important;} /* ignore */
```